# New Vehicle Steering Wheel Vibrates in drive but stops in Neutral/Park

Tags: steering, vibration, acura, tlx

I just bought this DEMO 2016 Acura TLX Tech with 5000KM on it. The dealership just did a fresh oil change around August.They also installed new winter tires for my vehicle too! I drove it for 1 day now, and I feel a slight vibration in my steering wheel when I put the vehicle in drive. However, the vibration stops when I let my vehicle in neutral or park. Is there something wrong with the car?

edit: I'm a new driver! And hopefully someone can give me tips to help maintain my car in top shape!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean to say that your steering vibrates while wheels are moving. 
If so then slight vibrations are common depending upon road condition, but if you are on smooth surface and it still vibrates then I would recommend you to check balancing (your dealer might forgot to balance it while switching to winter tires) of wheels and check alignment. And if these does not fixes your problem then I would suggest you to stay away from this car.
Also next time hand over the steering to someone with more experience and see if he can point out the issue.

Comment: The vibrations in the steering wheel kinda stops when I increase its speed.I notice it a lot when I'm stopped in a red light or when I'm reversing the vehicle. I know there should be a bit of vibration, but its a lot more compared to my 09 TSX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your motor mounts, while driving and come to a stop it vibrates and vibration stop when in park or neutral..motor mount have them check out